# How to simulate VOIP on audio

Tags: voip, simulator

I was looking over the web and didn't find:

Is there any tool, sdk to simulate voip on audio? for example - I take a lecture recording (.wav) - and want to get it as if it was conducted remotely via VOIP (with all the characteristics of Voip technology)?

Comment: Can you list the characteristics? What VoIP service? `ffmpeg` could reencode to speex at a particular bitrate.

Comment: I think you are looking for an IVR solution. For playing a pre recorded file ( .wav file)

Answer (score 1):

1. Prepare two tSIP or pjsua softphone instances for direct IP calling (for "receiving" softphone instance use binding to specific port). They may be on same PC. You may even make it more "real" by routing call through some VoIP operator, these calls are often free (if two numbers belong to same operator) and it easy to find free accounts (even if these would be time-limited trial accounts).
2. In softphone initiating connection (or receiving connection - doesn't matter really) select wav file as audio source. Select "Null" as audio output as you probably would not be interested in this audio direction.
3. In second softphone enable call recording (or just use speaker or headphones for real time). Record in stereo mode or make sure audio input device is set to "Null".
4. For testing multiple codecs enable few codecs (PCMU, PCMA, GSM, G.722 are commonly used) on one softphone instance and for each test only one codec on second instance.
5. Some command line pjsua parameters may allow you to simulate packet loss.

Comment: Does that scale? if I need to this on 30K files?

Comment: There is built in scripting and multiple softphone pairs can be used, although as this is real time test, possibly simulating real world conditions (packet loss), possibly with real VoIP operator that may limit call rate - this would scale poorly. Doing this on 30k files seems like overkill, perhaps just reencoding as suggested earlier would be sufficient.